# Is there a way to compress folders individually using 7zip on a large collection of folders?

Tags: batch, compression, 7-zip

How can 260 folders be zipped individually using 7zip with a single command?

The person who originally asked this question voluntarily deleted the post. Since it was an interesting task, I resurrected the question and developed a solution, which is posted below as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a script to accomplish that (omit the comments "//", which are shown for explanation):

```
@echo off
for /D %%G IN (*) DO (
    //This is my path to 7-Zip, it could be different for you
cd c:\program files\7-zip
    //This is the dir of the parent folder in which you want the subfolders to be zipped individually.
7z a  -t7z c:\users\user\desktop\folder\%%G.7z c:\users\user\desktop\folder\%%G -r )
pause
```

-t7z is the .7z archive format being used.

**To use the script:**

The way the script is written is assuming that you have a parent folder with sub directory that you want to zip individually (each sub directory in its own zip archive).

**Visual Representation:**

```
----Parent Directory
--------Sub Directory (to be zipped)
--------Sub Directory (to be zipped)
--------Sub Directory (to be zipped)
--------Sub Directory (to be zipped)
--------Sub Directory (to be zipped)
```

Lers say that the sub directories you want to zip are located in `C:\Users\Foo\Documents`. So it would look like:

```
----C:\Users\Foo\Documents
--------Foo1
--------Foo2
--------Foo3
--------Foo4
--------Foo5
```

So in the script i provided, you would edit the line:

```
7z a  -t7z c:\users\user\desktop\folder\%%G.7z c:\users\user\desktop\folder\%%G -r )
```

to say:

```
7z a  -t7z c:\Users\Foo\Documents\%%G.7z c:\Users\Foo\Documents\%%G -r )
```

So now we have to set our 7z.exe location so the script can run properly.

**NOTE: You do not have to do this if you succeed in setting the Environmental Variable for 7z.exe. For those who succeed, omit the line `cd c:\program files\7-zip`. To test if it worked or not, simply open `cmd.exe` and type in `7z`, if you get a list of options and parameters, then it worked and if not, then continue with the `cd` command.**

Find where you installed 7-Zip and copy the directory and add it after the `cd`. In the example, it will be installed in `C:\Program Files\7-Zip`. So the finished script will look like this:

```
@echo off
for /D %%G IN (*) DO (
cd C:\Program Files\7-Zip
7z a  -t7z c:\Users\Foo\Documents\%%G.7z c:\Users\Foo\Documents\%%G -r )
pause
```

now save the script as a `.bat` file extension, if using notepad you must change `Save as Type` to `All Files (".")`.

If written correctly, end result should look like this:
[image: Result]

**NOTE: If you have folders that have spaces, it wont output the entire name, but where the first word before the space. Ex: `Foo 1` will be archived as `Foo.7z` (no bueno). Same thing with more than one folder with the first word as `Foo` and `Foo 1`, they both run into the last problem i explained and when `Foo` is first archived, the archive for `Foo 1` will try to overwrite `Foo`'s because they have the same name. If you can find a work around this, Kudos to you!**

You may also want to try Tyler's version of my script, of course, his is more "universally compatible" and involves having `7z.exe` as an E.V. (Environmental Variable).

Comment: Can you add a sentence to the answer on how to use the script?

Comment: Updated it for ya :)

Comment: Nice job.  I already upvoted your question and answer.

Comment: You need quotes around `C:\Program Files\7-Zip` or the script will cd to c:\program

Comment: That never happens to me. Did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

This works for files not sub-folder in a parent folder
http://dropcanvas.com/w7u6a/3

http://dropcanvas.com/w7u6a/3

```
@echo off
cd /d %~dp0
rem 7z.exe path
set sevenzip=
if "%sevenzip%"=="" if exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\7-zip\7z.exe" set sevenzip=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\7-zip\7z.exe
if "%sevenzip%"=="" if exist "%ProgramFiles%\7-zip\7z.exe" set sevenzip=%ProgramFiles%\7-zip\7z.exe
if "%sevenzip%"=="" echo 7-zip not found&pause&exit
set extension=.mp4
for %%a in (*%extension%) do "%sevenzip%" a "%%~na.7z" "%%a"
pause
[/CODE]
```

Answer (score 1):

Write it like this and there won't be any problems.

```
7z a  -t7z "c:\users\user\desktop\folder\%%G.7z" c:\users\user\desktop\folder\%%G -r
```